# "Workspace needs to be loaded before it is used" on ng new

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-cli-v7

This code appears to me when I trying to run `ng new`

```sh
sarah @ sarah-Inspiron-5567 ~/Projects
└─ $ ▶ ls
sarah @ sarah-Inspiron-5567 ~/Projects
└─ $ ▶ ng new my-angular-app
Workspace needs to be loaded before it is used.
Error: Workspace needs to be loaded before it is used.
    at Workspace._assertLoaded (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace.js:69:19)
    at Workspace._getTool (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace.js:175:14)
    at Workspace.getCli (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace.js:157:21)
    at Object.getConfiguredPackageManager (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/config.js:131:32)
    at Object.getPackageManager (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/package-manager.js:32:35)
    at NewCommand.createWorkflow (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/schematic-command.js:156:47)
    at NewCommand.initialize (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/schematic-command.js:39:14)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:757:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
sarah @ sarah-Inspiron-5567 ~/Projects
└─ $ ▶
```

Information about my environment:

- node: v10.15.3
- npm: 6.4.1
- Angular-CLI: 7.3.8
- SO: Linux Mint 19.1

Comment: could you post your angular.json file? according to [this bug](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10757) it appears it might happen if your angular.json file has a syntax error in it

Comment: Theres no angular.json. I not created a project yet. I'm trying to create a new project

Comment: sorry, I meant angular-cli.json

Comment: I updated the command line output. I am in a empty folder and when I try to create a new angular app , I get that error.

Comment: I have the same issue on v7.2.0

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the *.angular-config.json* file in the root directory is causing this issue. After deleting it, the problem was gone:

```
rm ~/.angular-config.json
```

See also [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14591)